# SQL Collate Ordering

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx

The following Select orders the Locations table differently depending on the collation, why and how exactilly does the spanish collation puts 'Chiapas' as the last row?

```
CREATE TABLE Locations  
(Place varchar(15) NOT NULL);  
GO  
INSERT Locations(Place) VALUES ('Chiapas'),('Colima')  
                             , ('Cinco Rios'), ('California');  
GO  
--Apply an typical collation  
SELECT Place FROM Locations  
ORDER BY Place  
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS ASC;  
GO  
-- Apply a Spanish collation  
SELECT Place FROM Locations  
ORDER BY Place  
COLLATE Traditional_Spanish_ci_ai ASC;  
GO
```

First Query(Standard Collation):

```
Place
-------------
California
Chiapas
Cinco Rios
Colima
```

Second Query(Spanish Collation):

```
Place
-------------
California
Cinco Rios
Colima
Chiapas
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because CH comes after C in the Spanish collation.

Please have a look at the collation chart [here](http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.040A.1252.Traditional_Spanish_CI_AI.html).

[image]